# Does concavity of a function only tell us about the 'direction' (up/down) or it also tells 'magnitude' of curviness?

Tags: calculus

So, second derivative of a function tells you about the 'concavity' or 'curviness' of the graph.

Im very comfortable with the notion of how second derivative tells you the up/down curviness of graph.

But, does it also tell you magnitude of curviness?

Im confused because of this specific example -

y=x²

Second derivative is = 2

So, what does that mean? Is the graph equally concave at all points, with a 'concaveness' of 2?

Im confused because the graph looks differently concaved at different points visually, but how come second derivative be same for all points then?

What understanding am I lacking here?

Comment: Consider the physical metaphor of motion.  Second derivative of position with respect to time is "*Acceleration.*"

Comment: "Im confused because the graph looks differently concaved at different points visually" I think you are mistaking *looking differently curved* with *looking differently concaved*. As you have shown, the concavity is a constant. The graph of the function changes *curviness* in a consistent way (but I think that, without knowing about the functions, you won't be able to tell too much about the magnitude of the concavity just by glancing at the shape of a graph)

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of the curviness is related to the second derivative, but not exactly equal to it. Your intuition is leading you to the notation of the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature) of a graph. That Wikipedia page even works through the specific [example of a parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Parabola) if you're interested.